# Issue using IF=() function in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, if-statement, concatenation

I am new to this forum and I am seeking help with creating a function in Excel for data logging purposes. Basically I am trying to use Excel to write a macro simply by pressing "x" in certain cells. For instance, from cells A3-A6 I will have client's names listed there. In addition, I will have dates (of service) listed on the 2nd cell row and on.

```
                   9/20       9/21       9/22        9/24

John Doe                                  x

Sara Mitchell                             x               x

Christopher Acha                x
```

Now, I have the macro, I have everything I need in order to set this up. The only problem I am having is to make Excel write the macro for me. I am trying to use the IF=() function, but it limits me to 255 characters, and it tells me to use the concatenate function. All I am trying to do is basically tell Excel that if a certain cell IS true, I would mark it by hitting x; meaning that if a person came on the 24th for service, I would hit x and from there excel would automatically write what I tell it to (in a different sheet or cell). I am stuck here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the macro look like? Where are you getting the data that tells you which date they came? There's other ways than a giant if statement, just depends on where your criteria come from I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you have a macro that works, so I'm assuming you want to know how to trigger it automatically when you enter data into a cell.

In your worksheet code use a change event and call your macro from here and pass the range you sent.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   myMacro(Target)
End Sub
```

You'll probably want to add in additional code to test that the cell changed is within a certain range before calling your macro.